# Appach: What permissions should public_html have?

Tags: linux, apache, public-html

I have an appache server running on Linux - CentOS.

Searching around the web I found several answers to the question in the title. Can someone please provide a reliable reference to this critical question?

Comment: [What are the best linux permissions to use for my website?](http://serverfault.com/q/357108)